# GitHub Actions: rubocop errors out, but the code is not from my repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, github-actions, rubocop

When running the workflow in GitHub actions, rubocop errors out, but the code that it complains about is **not** present in my repo. How can I fix this?

**Error:**

```
Run bin/rubocop --parallel
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-import-1.1.0/.rubocop.yml: Lint/EndAlignment has the wrong namespace - should be Layout
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-import-1.1.0/.rubocop.yml: Metrics/LineLength has the wrong namespace - should be Layout
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-import-1.1.0/.rubocop.yml: Style/ElseAlignment has the wrong namespace - should be Layout
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-import-1.1.0/.rubocop.yml: Style/SpaceInsideParens has the wrong namespace - should be Layout
Error: The `Lint/HandleExceptions` cop has been renamed to `Lint/SuppressedException`.
(obsolete configuration found in vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-import-1.1.0/.rubocop_todo.yml, please update it)
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

**GitHub Actions workflow yml file:**

```yml
name: Verify
on: [push]

jobs:
  linters:
    name: Linters
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Ruby and install gems
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          bundler-cache: true

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 10.13.0
      - name: Find yarn cache location
        id: yarn-cache
        run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)"
      - name: JS package cache
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache.outputs.dir }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-
      - name: Install packages
        run: |
          yarn install --pure-lockfile
          sudo apt-get -yqq install libpq-dev
          gem install bundler
          bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3
      - name: Run linters
        run: |
          bin/rubocop --parallel

  tests:
    name: Tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:11
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: myapp
          POSTGRES_DB: myapp_test
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""
        ports: ["5432:5432"]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Ruby and install gems
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          bundler-cache: true

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 10.13.0
      - name: Find yarn cache location
        id: yarn-cache
        run: echo "::set-output name=dir::$(yarn cache dir)"
      - name: JS package cache
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache.outputs.dir }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-
      - name: Install packages
        run: |
          gem install bundler
          bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3
          
      - name: Setup test database
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          PGHOST: localhost
          PGUSER: myapp
        run: |
          bundle exec rails db:create
          bundle exec rails db:migrate

      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          bundle exec rails test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already noticed there is not really a benefit in running RuboCop against third-party code and external gems because they are not really under your control and you certainly do not want to "fix" them.

Therefore I suggest excluding folders with external code, for example, gems in the `vendor/bundle` folder. This can be done by adding the following lines to your project's `.rubycop.yml` configuration file:

```
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - 'vendor/bundle/**/*'
```

See the [RuboCop docs](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html#includingexcluding-files) about excluding files and folders.